# How to connect iphone emulator to selgrid 2?

Tags: iphone, ruby, selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have done all the steps listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver) to setup a webdriver backed iphone emulator.
I am also able to run my scripts of the emulator when running them locally using the below code while creating my driver instance.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://localhost:3001/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :iphone
```

What I intend to do is connect this emulator to sel grid 2, which has the hub running remotely on a windows machine.

**Can some one please share the command to start the selenium webdriver node on the mac machine(coincidentally my local machine).**

Some thing like

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role webdriver -hubHost remotewindowmachine.com -hubPort 4444 -hub http://remotewindowmachine.com:4444/grid/register -host iphoneIP/hub -port 3001 -browser browserName=iphone
```

which throws an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 3001.
```

Which seems kind of obvious, but i am confused as to whats to be done about it.

So can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to run the node registration command to register it in a grid.

**The reason for your error**

In iPhone(and emulator) when you start iWebDriverApp it starts in port 3001 as remote control. So when you try to start another node in the same machine on same port(3001) its going to throw this error.

**The solution**

I have not tried it in an emulator, but in the actual device. After installing the iWebDriverApp in your device, you need to set the hub details for the app. This can be done by going to **Settings->iWebDriverApp**. you will find textboxes to specify Hub URL and the port. Then restart the iWebDriverApp again. Your iphone will be in the grid.

Comment: yes i agree with you on the first part, that the error will obviously be thrown because i would be attempting to run a node and RC on the same port. Unfortunately I would not have a physical Iphone device to test against. And using the emulator is my only option. Also and going to iphone emulator settings, gives me ONLY one field, that of the port. So I cannot implement using the second technique. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Oh, I thought you will have the same setting in emulator too. Because thats what they have mentioned in selenium wiki.. Here is the excerpt from wiki.....Hooking it up to a Selenium Grid2
Once you have the app installed on your device or emulator. Go to the iOS Settings app. Near the bottom there will be an "iWebDriver" settings area. Going into that you should see settings for Server port and Grid Host/Port. Fill in the details as desired.

Comment: exactly what I thought, unfortunately there is only one field that being the Port number. which is kind of useless.