# Setup Selenium GRID 2 on Mac with iPhone and Android

Tags: selenium, android-emulator, socket.io, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Hi I am trying to setup Selenium GRID II on Mac server using iPhone simulator and Android emulator. I am able to connect iPhone to Grid and even I am able to start the test. But while connecting Android Emulator I get following error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=MAC, browserName=android, version=}
Command duration or timeout: 161 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18040', time: '2012-11-02 09:44:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at com.Softcrylic.Automation.Testing.WebDriverTest.setUp(WebDriverTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=MAC, browserName=android, version=}
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18040', time: '2012-11-02 09:44:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:111)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:452)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:894)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:948)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Softcrylic.Automation.Testing.WebDriverTest.tearDown(WebDriverTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**What I am doing?**

1.) I install android-standalone-server.apk on Android and forwarded port 8080 to 8080 using adb.

2.) Than started new node which connects to Grid as given below

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 8080 -browser browserName="Android",version="4",platform="MAC"
```

What's wrong I am doing?

Comment: on a side note can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523649/how-to-connect-iphone-emulator-to-selgrid-2

Answer (score 1):

2 things to try.

1: try running the node launch command with this updated syntax: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 8080 -browser "browserName=android,version=4,platform=MAC"`

2: follow the updated instructions here:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get an Android test working.  I followed the instructions detailed at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

Don't start a local node to connect to your hub.  Instead, after starting the WebDriver on your Android device, forward the port using the `adb -s {id} forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` command.  That is it.  You are ready to test.  You have modify your test to now connect to the port you are forwarding.

I use selenium grid, so I had to modify my tests to accomodate the different hub when performing android tests.  I can't connect to the selenium hub, instead I have to connect directly to the android device as if it is a hub.  I could not find a way to register the android device as a node with my main selenium hub that I use.

In your android tests, you need to connect to the `http://localhost:8080/wd/hub` when creating your RemoteWebDriver.  This will connect you to the hub on the android device and your tests will work from there.

Wish there was a way to configure the WebDriver on the android device to register as a node with an existing hub.  I am sure there is, but I haven't figured it out.